# Find Record from user table which in not in other 6 different table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to write a `T-SQL` query that fines `userId` from `UserTable`
where the `userId` is not in other six tables. The `userId` is `PK` of `UserTable` and `FK` in the others tables.

Which is the best way to occomplish this?

I have written in this way :

```
select distinct userId ,Email,FName from
 (
    select user_id as userId,user_email as Email,user_firstname as FName from bb_user
    where user_id not in ( select user_id from bb_acquire_prvider)
    UNION ALL  
    select user_id as userId,user_email as Email,user_firstname as FName from bb_user
    where user_id not in ( select user_id from bb_sell_seek)

 ) as userId
 order by userId asc
```

Comment: Try where not exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose one of these ways:

[Should I use NOT IN, OUTER APPLY, LEFT OUTER JOIN, EXCEPT, or NOT EXISTS?](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)

I prefer `NOT EXISTS` for the reasons mentioned there.

```
SELECT t1.id FROM Table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id
)
AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM Table3 t3 WHERE t1.id = t3.id
)
....
```

Comment: Or use only one `NOT EXISTS` and `UNION` the tables

Comment: @Serpiton: works also, but can be less efficient. Why should the database link all tables and remove all duplicates if i just want to know if a given ID is in t2,t3,t4,t5 or t6? If the second table already contains that ID, the rest of the tables can be ignored. Imho multiple `NOT EXIST` are more readable and maintainable(f.e. if i want to have a different logic for a table) and in this case also more efficient.

Comment: I was thinking of `UNION ALL` but only wrote `UNION`

Comment: I am getting problem : I want user id which is not exist in other 6 different table .....my result coming wrong using UNION ALL

Comment: Ok, where do i use UNION ALL?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT - I wanted to add that this solution only returns id's that don't exist in all 6 tables. So I'm not sure if this is what you were looking for or if you didn't want it to return any that exist in any one of the 6 tables. Hope that makes sense.

I used `not exists` and did a `join` on the other tables.

```
select * from table1 t1
where not exists
  (
    select * from table2 t2
    join table3 t3 on t2.userid = t3.userid
    join table4 t4 on t2.userid = t4.userid
    join table5 t5 on t2.userid = t5.userid
    join table6 t6 on t2.userid = t6.userid
    join table7 t7 on t2.userid = t7.userid
    where t1.userid = t2.userid
  )
```